# Zend_Rest_Controller upload file

Tags: php, zend-framework, amazon-s3, zend-rest

I have no strong php or Zend background, please bear with me if I asked silly questions.

I am trying to upload an image to Amazon Web Service S3, via Zend Framework's REST controller.

Most examples i found are about Zend Form, which is not suitable in my case, as I use REST POST.

I believe the file had to be converted into stream of bytes, and send to the Zend_Rest_Controller, but I have no idea how to do.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zend Framework has a component to handle Amazon s3 interfacing, check it out at:
[Zend Framework Amazon S3 documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.service.amazon.s3.html)

Comment: I saw that site, but the methods to upload file are putObject(), putFile() and putFileStream(). they require a file name. The problem is, how I put my file on the server, so the file name can be passed into those methods?

Comment: I realized that my problem is about $_FILES, use $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] will get the uploaded image path.